# Source Indexing with Git

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration, source-server

I am trying to start using source indexing alongside Git on our build server (TeamCity).

I download this project: [SourceServer-GitExtensions](https://github.com/joliver/SourceServer-GitExtensions)

While running it i noticed warnings/errors. digging into the script (which is PERL based), i noticed the script runs this function:

```
sub GetSha1OfFirstCommand {
my $result = `git rev-list --reverse master`;
my @ids = split(/\n/, $result);
return($ids[0]);
}
```

This is run in an attempt to get the repository's id (id of the first commit i assume).

The problem is, we are currently not using the master branch.

My question is -- is this a proper and robust way of getting the "Repository Id" ? Can i run something else to get the "current branch that is checked out" and not master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trys to get the commit id of the first commit. `git rev-list --reverse master` and getting the first id, which is what the code you have given does, should work ( mostly) as all the git repos come with a master branch and the first commit is done on master and any branch would have branched off from that. Mostly because a branch can have it's own history (`git checkout --orphan`) or there may not be a master. In that case a more robust one would be `git rev-list --reverse HEAD`. This would work even on a bare repo.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Though standard to have a master branch, it's not required and the name can be changed.

Comment: @Guildencrantz - that is why I said `mostly`

Answer (score 3):

The minimal changes would be to run this instead:

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD
```

This will give you the revision list for the current branch.

Comment: This works for me on a bare repo, as long as `HEAD` in that repo points to the correct branch.

Comment: It just occurred to me, even if you're on a different branch, as long as you had the same initial commit, it doesn't matter what branch you check initially.  If you had two roots, then it will change.